# jQuery ajax form.submit() in .done always triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using the following Javascript  to check a form before actually submitting.

```
$('#homesubmit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$("#inputcode").val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#inputcode").qtip({
            content: 'Please enter code!.',
            style: {
                /* Other qtip settings and stuff */
        })
    }
    else {
        var jqxhr = $.post( "<?php echo base_url().'ajaxhandler?action=checkcodehome'?>", $( "#startcode" ).serialize())
            .done(function() {
                alert( "Correct!");
                /* // If code is correct, please do submit the form...
                $.('#startcode').submit(); */
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Wrong!");
                /* Maken a qtip tooltip*/
            });
    }
});
```

Ajaxhandler gives a 200 OK header when the form is ready to be submitted and a 404 when that's not the case. This works wonderful with the alerts that I've got in my example, but when I want to call `.submit()` on the form on succes the form is submitted on `.fail` as well.

I guess I could have my ajaxhandler return a json with true/false and check that value in `.done`, but that seems redundant since there's no data that I want to send.

Why is the `alert()` triggered that corresponds to the response, but is `$.('#startcode').submit()` always called?

Kind regards

Comment: doesn't `done` fires once the response is received, weather successful or not?  try `.success()`

Comment: whether the `Correct` alert is appearing in the case of error

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I thought .done was only fired on success, but apparently that's .success.

Comment: great. will add as an answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that gets fired when a jquery ajax call is successfull is `success` 
as per the [$.post docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

`done()` is fired once the ajax call has returned, but that doesnt nessecarly means its returned successfully.

You can also have your success call inline, and use extra methods for different responses, such as:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.done(function() {
    alert("returned");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("fail");
})
.always(function() {
    alert("fall back/always fires");
});
```

Comment: It's been a while, just saw that I hadn't accepted this answer. Accepting it now for future readers.

Comment: Thanks @user2693053

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return false on fail situation